# Portable speaker project

Tags: charge, portable

I would like to create my portable speaker box. I am new so please be patient with me. My idea is use TP4056 chargers to charge two li-ion, then via step-up boost modules feed PAM8403 3W amp, and PAM8610 10W amp. I will use two 4Ohm 3W bass speakers and two 4Ohm 6W full-range speakers. Enclosure will be from wood. I don't know if it's good to use a sealed enclosure or one with bass reflex. Question is, if the scheme is correct or incorrect.

[image]

Comment: The lower battery only ever seems to receive charge.

Comment: The power conversion architecture makes sense -- at your core you are battery powered (missing a discharge connection from the bottom battery). Replacing the TP4056s with a wide input-range charger gives you plenty of options in that space and properly designed, that can be very modular. You could delete a power supply if you decide to use 2x PAM8610.

Comment: Something to check: Those two 800 mAh Lithium Ion batteries aren't going to be able to provide sufficient power to the amplifiers for very long per charge, are they?

Comment: Lower case "i" as the very first word, then "pls" still all on the first line.  That's where I tuned out.  -1 for the gross disrespect, and closing since after giving up on the first line I have no idea what is being asked.  You have forgotten that we are all volunteers here that aren't obligated to answer.

Comment: In your diagram the lower battery positive terminal isn't connected to anything except the charger.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things wrong with this.

1) I would never choose to Boost from a battery except for very small current loads. Boost converters draw an incredible amount of peak current that your batteries likely won't be able to take. This is often why you see cells in series since the buck converter's current draw is much less stress on the battery. Boosting from the 5V supply to charge the batteries would be much easier since you can size the supply to meet the current needs of the boost.

2) Always size you speakers so that they exceed the wattage your amp can produce. Those 6W speakers are going to blow out when you crank it loud.

3) Never use wood for speakers. It sucks. The acoustic properties of wood do not make good speakers. All the "wood" speakers you see are actually MDF with a wood veneer (or vinyl) applied over top.

4) Sealed versus ported are all things that depend on the actual speakers themselves. This is always a nice site to visit to help with that. [Speaker Box Calculator](http://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Calculator/SpeakerBoxEnclosure/)

5) Misc other things I've noticed that don't strike me as a good idea:

- There's no signal buffering amp on the input. It might also be nice if you showed the filter you were going to use to pass the bass to one speaker set and the rest to the other.
- One of your amps has a DC volume control, the other doesn't. That means when you turn the volume down, the bass will still be blasting.
- No mention of non-linearity compensating networks (Zobel, Notch, D-Pad)

Comment: lithium batters like all secondary batteries can supply crazy peak loads  and te convertes will capacitors on the input anyway.

Comment: @Jasen, low Ohm speakers require large amounts of current. that's 8V and 2.5A to power those two 6W speakers at full. Even a 100% efficiency boost would need to source 5.4A. That's well outside of anything I've seen two 800mAh batteries provide in parallel. So no, even if they supply peak they'll never supply average.

Comment: those lithium cells are good for 8A or more

Comment: @Jasen, If you can find any 3.6V 800mAh Li-ion that states in it's datasheet that it can safely source 4A continuously (for both 100% efficiency boost converters, which don't exist) then you can win magic internet points.

Comment: hmm, yeah, I can find li-poly with that capability but not li-ion

Comment: @Dave hmm, then i need replace PAM8610 with PAM8403, right ? Or what about adding some electrolytic capacitors ? Is low-pass filter required, if there are only 2 bass speakers connected to one amp ? If yes, what is simplest (for me) low-pass filter ? RC filter ? Same about Compensating networks, from what i read on the internet, it helps neutralize the effects of the driver’s voice coil inductance (but to me, it sounds like its the same thing as low-pass filter). Thank you

Comment: @user2945696, So an input circuit can look like what ever you need it to. Again, in order to design the filter network, you should know where you're putting the cut-off frequency and how your speakers respond at those frequencies. The LP section of the filter should go to the woofers and the HP side should go to the full ranges. That filter should be between the input and the amps. Compensating network make a voice coil **look** resistive to the amp. This is more important for Class-D, since they're not linear amps. If you don't want to blow out the 6W's then you can fix the volume maximum.

Comment: @Dave again thanks for info, now its more clear to me. Last thing - if i skip signal buffering, will be audio only less louder, or?

Comment: @user2945696, signal buffering just acts as a way of disconnecting the signal's source impedance from your device. It allows you to set up the input conditions to your circuit that you want without assuming they will be given to you. It also works the other way around to protect your input from anything that might come back through. After all, not every amp can drive every load.

Answer (score 0):

looks fairly good, but you seem to be over-thinking it.

lithium cells are fairly happy connected in parallel and that simplifies things enough that you won't make simple like forgetting to connect one of the batteries to a load. and will save you one charger.

to improve shelf-life fit a power switch between the boost converters and the lithium cells.[image]

Comment: Thank you for the correction, btw.: just asking,will something happen if i leave there two TP4056 ? When i was making this scheme i thought it will speed up charging, but now i am not sure.

Comment: I think that would be fine as it has both a current and a voltage limit they will share the load well and can can work together cooperatively.